# Core Data deleting one element NSManagedObject Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

So I was trying to delete an element from CoreData and followed other answers in Stackoverflow. Here's the code to delete an element from datamodel when the button is clicked

```
moneyManager.moneys.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
do {
       context.deleteObject(moneyManager.moneys[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)
       try context.save()
}catch {
       print("Error not saved")
}
```

There is an error that I get:

> Cast from 'money' to unrelated type 'NSManagedObject' always fails

Now I have seen other people using arrays of AnyObject?, yet I don't understand where this array should specifically come from and where I should declare it.

moneyManager is class that has an array of moneys which stores data of every money transaction done by the user. I think I should delete data not from here but from the entity itself, am I right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What actual type is moneys? By the way, there is a fatal error in your code: The object deleted from the moneys array and the object deleted from the context are most likely different.

Comment: It's of type money, which is a struct and has a name as String and moneyAmount as Double

Comment: The object deleted from the context must be of type `NSManagedObject`. Are you using `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: I fear that I am not aware of such a thing. Where should I be using it specifically?

Comment: Never mind, but there must be a relation between the items in the moneys array and the corresponding Core Data `NSManagedObject` objects. You can't save a struct type in Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I figured it out! What I did was simply creating a new Array of NSManagedObject and fetched the data from my data model into it. Then I simply deleted the element from the Array and it somehow works

Comment: It's cumbersome to use two different arrays for actually the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete element from managedObjectContext...

```
appDelegateObj.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(dataArray[indexPath.row])
do {
      try appDelegateObj.managedObjectContext.save()
      dataArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
} catch {
      let saveError = error as NSError
      print(saveError)
}
```

Here one tutorial that have complete CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) operation described.

You have to see that. This is very simple.

[**Reference Link**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/06/crud-operations-using-code-data-swift.html)

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at this tutorial, thanks for sharing